# How to fix: SQL search in multiple joined tables no result

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, innodb

I have a database with 4 inner-joined tables (name them A, B, C and D). If the search conditions after WHERE clause are in table A/B/C, it works. If my search condition in table D, there is no result. If table B isn't joined in the query, there are results with table D conditions.

I am using phpmyadmin and InnoDB.

Here is the code that gives 0 result:

```
SELECT A.1, A.2, B.1, B.2, D.1
  FROM A
  INNER JOIN D
  ON A.3 = D.2
  INNER JOIN C
  ON A.4 = C.1
  INNER JOIN B
  ON C.1 = B.3
  WHERE D.3 IN ('example_search');
```

If I remove the B join it gives me the expected results and the desired D.1 values:

```
SELECT A.1, A.2, /*B.1, B.2,*/ D.1
  FROM A
  INNER JOIN D
  ON A.3 = D.2
  INNER JOIN C
  ON A.4 = C.1
  /*INNER JOIN B
  ON C.1 = B.3*/
  WHERE D.3 IN ('example_search');
```

It also works if my search conditions are not in the D table:

```
SELECT A.1, A.2, B.1, B.2, D.1
  FROM A
  INNER JOIN D
  ON A.3 = D.2
  INNER JOIN C
  ON A.4 = C.1
  INNER JOIN B
  ON C.1 = B.3
  WHERE B.1 IN ('example_search')
  AND A.2 IN ('example_search_2');
```

And it returns the correct D.1 values as well.
example_search and example_search_2 are from an other database query, so the problem is not typo (at least not in the condition).
I don't know where I made the mistake.
Thanks for the replies.
PS.: my English is bad, sorry for that.

Comment: does your B table have values that meet the join criteria?

Comment: Try a Left Join on B

Comment: Yes, B.3 was populated by SQL syntax (from C table) and returns the expected values.

Comment: It works with Left Join on B but It does not return the values of the B table.
C table is used to join A to B.

Comment: Thanks for the left join tip, because of that I found the bug, The database is not my work and it has a strange feature in table C, all the needed value with the reference ID of C table are null values (as I understand there is small "tables" in the C table). The content I need is between 2 reference ID (so INNER JOIN B ON C.1 + 1 = B.3 works).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips because of that I found the bug, The database is not my work and it has a strange feature in table C, all the needed values with the reference ID of C table are null values (as I understand there is small "tables" in the C table). The content I need is between 2 reference ID (so INNER JOIN B ON C.1 + 1 = B.3 works).